# Help with Legendre Plot Matlab

Tags: computer-science, matlab, computational-mathematics

I've written a code to change a Chebyshev into a Legendre Polynomial, however it will not plot the graph after and I'm not sure why the graph will not plot?
The code i have is:
function LegendrePoly(n)

```
x=[-1:0.01:1]';
M=zeros(length(x),n);
M(:,1)=ones(length(x),1);
M(:,2)=x;
for k=3:n
    M(:,k)=(2*k-1)*x.*M(:,k-1)-(k-1).*M(:,k-2)/k;  
end
plot(x,M,'LineWidth',2);
grid;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relationship for Legendre polynomials is:

$$kP_{k}(x)=(2k-1)xP_{k}(x)-(k-1)P_{k-2}(x)$$

Thus, you have two corrections to bring:

- coefficient $(k-1)$ instead of $(k-2)$ for the last term, and
- division by $k$ that, at present, is only on the last term: it should be on all the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks made them corrections, but i still can't get it to plot

Comment: You should invert $plot(M(:,k),x,\cdots \rightarrow plot(x,M(:,k),\cdots$ and I have checked that now, everything works. But it is extremely slow: there are much more efficient ways to program it, by making the recurrence relationship bear on polynomial coefficients only.

Comment: Working now thank you.

Comment: As you are new on this site, let me say you that it is the habit to **check** the answer (see the others answers) when the issue is considered as completed.